# Receiving Invalid glob match expression for wildcard security rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement the rule outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56047977/1604072

```
match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

This is yielding this error: *Invalid glob match expression. Glob matches 
are permitted as the last segment in a match declaration path.*

Is this the only/proper way to write this now?:

```
match /{path=**}{
    match /collectionItems/{collectionItem} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For future users, just found [this bit of documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups). Not sure why I wasn’t able to find it originally:

> **Secure and query documents based on collection groups**
>
> In your security rules, you must explicitly allow collection group
>   queries by writing a rule for the collection group:
>
> 1. Make sure `rules_version = '2';` is the first line of your ruleset. Collection group queries require the [new recursive wildcard `{name=**}`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) behavior of security rules version 2.
> 2. Write a rule for you collection group using `match /{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}`.

Answer (score 1):

simply replace `/{path=**}/` with `/{prefix=**}/` and it should work

In the end it should look like this:

```
match /{prefix=**}/posts/{post} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```